# Problems with using aliases on update mysql command

Tags: php, mysql

I'm encountering a mysql syntax issue wit the following update query command and I'm not sure how to overcome this.
It looks fine to me :/ could anyone help me out please?

This is the query:

```
UPDATE r 
SET r.status_code = 7, r.last_updated = now()
FROM record r
LEFT JOIN held_proposals h ON h.proposal_id = r.proposal_id
WHERE r.proposal_id = h.proposal_id AND h.end_date < now() AND r.student_record_id = 46;
```

this is the error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM record r
>   LEFT JOIN held_proposals h ON h.proposal_id = r.proposal_id
>   WHE' at line 3

the table structure for each table:

held proposals:

[image: held_proposals table]

record:

[image: record tabls]

Really need to sort this out in the next 30 minutes. please help! thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

Try this untested query:

```
UPDATE record r  LEFT JOIN held_proposals h ON h.proposal_id = r.proposal_id
SET r.status_code = 7, r.last_updated = now()
WHERE h.end_date < now() AND r.student_record_id = 46;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response however its updated it for all the records and i need it to just update the ones which have the end date set to before now. any ideas?

Comment: basically i want to update the status for records in the record table if the end_date in the held_proposals table is set to before now(). so any records from a minute a go, a day ago. if you know what i mean.

Comment: @user610 so your query should work. or try DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)